# How to replace all linebreaks in the start of string c#

Tags: c#

I've seen a lot of questions on how to replace all linebreaks.
However I have a scenario where I would like to replace all linebreaks in the start of the string only, there can be none, one or multiple and there is no way to know beforehand how many linebreaks it will be.

**Question:**
How do I remove all linebreaks that may occour before the string?
any help or input appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `.Trim()`?

Comment: `string result = source.TrimStart('\n');` or `string result = source.TrimStart('\n', '\r');` if you want to remove carriage returns as well

Comment: Try it with regex. Your pattern must be something like `^\n*`.

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't even know TrimStart existed. That seemed to work very good!

Comment: Trim  + start, left, right, end are pretty common across language. here is C# doc about this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove all leading occurrences of a set of characters, use `String.TrimStart`. Its prototype is:

`public string TrimStart (params char[] trimChars);`

In `trimChars` you put `\n`, in your case.